# PHP - get line number of regex result

Tags: php, css, regex, arrays

I'm trying to write some PHP that will read a CSS file, find all occurrences of the @group comment, and their line number. This is what I have so far, but it's returning the character count rather than the line number.

```
$file = 'master.css';
$string = file_get_contents($file);

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\/\* @group.*?\*\//m', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
list($capture, $offset) = $matches[0];
$line_number = substr_count(substr($string, 0, $offset), "\n") + 1;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) rather than [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents). The difference is that `file()` returns the file contents as an array, one element per line, rather than as a string like `file_get_contents` does. I should note that `file()` returns the newline character at the end of each line as part of the array element. If you don't want that, add the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag as a second parameter.

From there, you can use [`preg_grep()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to return only the elements in the initial array. You can read their indexes to determine which lines matched, if you only want the line numbers:

An example:

**myfile.txt:**

```
hello world
how are you
say hello back!
```

**line_find.php:**

```
$filename = "myfile.txt";
$fileContents = file($filename);

$pattern = "/hello/";
$linesFound = preg_grep($pattern, $fileContents);

echo "<pre>", print_r($linesFound, true), "</pre>";
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello world

    [2] => say hello back!
)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a good solution... I always forget about `preg_grep()`. However, if he wants to support comments that span multiple lines, this won't work. (But that technicality may be something that doesn't really matter if he knows how his files are formatted.)

Comment: @konforce If OP needs to support multiple lines, your solution won't work either. I can't really think of a way to get around that either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if he were to do a matching group around the exact word he's looking for that PHP would give him the index of that as well (re: preg_match).

Comment: Thanks @AgentConundrum. This has been driving me crazy. Your answer definitely gets me closer to my end result. I'd not ever heard of `preg_grep()`. Nice.

Comment: @simplethemes You're quite welcome. PHP has all sorts of fiddly little functions that people forget exist.

Answer (score 4):

This is not going to be optimal, but if you don't care about that :

```
$line_number = 1 + substr_count($string, "\n", 0, $index);
```

It's just counting the number of new line characters found up until that index you get from the offset capture.